# How to select bit depth of ADC in MCU to use

Tags: microcontroller, adc

I trying to measure the signal with 1% error with reference voltage 3.3 V.

In my MCU ([Renesas RA2A1](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/ra-cortex-m-mcus/ra2a1-32-bit-microcontrollers-48mhz-arm-cortex-m23-and-integration-24-bit-sigma-delta-adc)) 2 ADC are available. One of them with 16 bit and the other one is a 24 bit sigma ADC.

How do I decide which one to use?

Comment: @kruemi Instead of rolling back to a version with spelling errors, improve on the last version instead?

Comment: @winny our edits overlapped. I started editing before your edit apeared but took a break. I wouldn't roll back, I wouldn't even know how ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring noise, an n-bit ADC means that it outputs a reading in n-bits. Since each bit can represent two states: 0 or 1 to represent a binary number, that means that the reading is given such that it up the measurement scale into 2^n steps. So if you want +/-1% error over 3.3V, that means at most 33mV per step.

So if you have a 10-bit ADC that is measuring a full scale of 0-5V, it would be dividing that 5V up into 2^10 steps which is 4.88mV per step.